# Android invoke mail problem if the screen have video

Tags: android, email, invoke, android-videoview

I have a activity which has a VideoView and a button for share. On touch of share button, it invokes the mail client. Here is my code:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phrasevideo);


        //extraDataHelper.getPhraseDetails(phraseId);
        btnshare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnshare);




        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "extras/hello.mp4");
        Uri video = Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath());            

        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    btnshare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});
        videoView.start();



        btnshare.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/html"); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{""}); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Language Hostess"); 
                String emailText = "<html><body><p>Hi friends</p></body></html>";
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailText));
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"), 1);
                return false;
            }});

    }
```

Everything is working fine. But when I am coming back to the app after sending or discarding the mail, the videoView is just black. Here I like to mention that the share button appears only when the video is not playing.  Why it is happening? What is the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to return true at the end of your onTouch method to indicate that you have handled the event.

As to why the share button appears only when the video is not playing, it's because you have not apportioned space for it in your view (the view that holds the video). You will need to add it to a context menu, or option menu, for the user to select.

As to why the screen is black, it probably has something to do with you not handling the return to your activity after the "sharing" activity. Be sure to have an onReturn method delineated.